# Multi-threading the Evaluation of Individuals in the GALib's GAPopulation

Tags: c++, genetic-algorithm, galib

From the GALib code the evaluation of individuals is done in a sequential manner as shown in the code snippet below.

```
void GAPopulation::DefaultEvaluator(GAPopulation &p) {

    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++)
        p.individual(i).evaluate();

}
```

However, I want to be able to modify this behaviour to evaluate a number of individuals in multiple threads to speed up the process. Also the `DefaultEvaluator` function is static.

Comment: Do you have to access the individual via an index or would there be an option to use iterators? If the latter would be the case, you could simply use the parallel version of [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) (assuming you can use C++17)…

Comment: This is a very old software. The individuals are accessed via index as show in the code ```p.individual(i)```.